# Spring: Initialize multiple connection pools at startup

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling

I want to initialize multiple connection pools at context startup by reading connection parameters from a database table. Basically I want to  address following two things

1. Read connection properties from database not the properties   file.
2. Their are multiple connection pool(rows in db) details.

So my question is How can I iterate over list of rows returned by database in spring-context file and create multiple data-source objects and store them (Lets say in a map) with a unique key?

Databse table structure are somewhat like following:

```
+--------------+----------------+---------------+
| DBSERVERNAME | DBDRIVERCLASS  | DBMINPOOLSIZE |
+--------------+----------------+---------------+
| Server1      | Mysql-Driver   |            10 |
| Server2      | Oracle-Driver  |            20 |
| Server3      | DB2-Driver     |            10 |
+--------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Let me know if more details are needed. Thanks.

Comment: maybe this can be useful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28893/Loading-Application-Properties-from-a-Database