# Spring Boot application.yml set datasource property globally, being ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, connection-pooling

I have a Spring Boot 1.5 app which is configured with an `application.yml` file.
I need to manage the connection pool which is default - Tomcat.

The problem is that the `application.yml` has a `datasources` property for several datasources.
My global `datasource.max-active=10` (UPDATE: `datasource.tomcat.max-active=10` is ignored too) is being completely ignored (I created a test to see what datasource is being injected, and default `maxActive` in them is set to 100). I have to add it to every datasource separately to make the pool work the way I need it to.

The `application.yml` looks like this (this is only part of it), and it creates datasource with `maxActive=10`, but there is bunch of repetitions:

```
spring:
  .... #bunch of stuff, deleted for simplicity
  datasource: #Added by me, ignored by Spring
    max-active: 10 #Added by me, ignored by Spring
datasources:
  datasource1:
    url: jdbc:mysql://url:port1
    max-active: 10 #Added by me, works
  datasource2:
    url: jdbc:mysql://url:port2
    max-active: 10 #Added by me, works
```

Question: what is the correct way to set the `max-active` property globally to avoid this repetition?
Thanks.

Comment: use `spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active` note the 'tomcat'

Comment: @DirkDeyne No, I tried this before and tried this right now after your comment, this being ignored too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using multiple data sources, spring boot does not provide a default data source auto-configuration. This also means you have to provide connection pool properties for each data source. I don't think it's possible to set it globally. 
Instead, you can use the placeholder to set it once and use it everywhere.

```
custom:
 max-active: 10 
spring:
datasources:
  datasource1:
    url: jdbc:mysql://url:port1
    max-active: ${custom.max-active}
  datasource2:
    url: jdbc:mysql://url:port2
    max-active: ${custom.max-active}
```

You can find more info here: [How to setup multiple connection pools when multiple datasources are used in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876443/how-to-setup-multiple-connection-pools-when-multiple-datasources-are-used-in-spr)